# Identification of variable value changing in .GlobalEnv in R

Tags: r, hash, trace

I want to continue series of strange questions.
So, I have a earlier task: I need to identify variables, which values were changed via same code execution. 
I found only 3 ways to realize it now:
1) use "track" package,
2) use tracemem,
3) use hashing.

I can't use "track" package because of R.NET limitations (also I've found that the problem I described in [Incorrect work of track package in R.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798029/incorrect-work-of-track-package-in-r-net) realizes in RStudio - there is also difference between R console execution and RStudio execution, RStudio execute this code like R.NET).

So, I have just only 2 ways - hash (for example, from hashr package) and tracemem.
I need to know, is it correct:
1) tracemem and hash could be used for all R types - internal or custom.
2) tracemem and hash haven't collisions in R realization.

Maybe is there other way to identify variable value change?

Thank you.

P.S.

Code for "track"

```
library(track);
options("digits.secs"=8);
track.start(clobber = "vars", dir = file.path(tempdir(), 'rdatadir123456'));

startTime <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time());

aaa <- 5; 
bbb <- 6;

environmentTrace <- track.summary(); 
variableNames <- attr(environmentTrace, "row.names");
modifiedTime <- environmentTrace$modified;

changedVariablesName <- unlist(
                    sapply(1:length(variableNames),          
                           function(i)
                           {
                               if ((modifiedTime[i] > startTime) && (variableNames[i] != "startTime"))
                               {
                                   return (variableNames[i]);
                               }
                           })
                          );

changedVariableValues <- sapply(changedVariablesName, function(elem) get(elem));
changedVariableList <- setNames(as.list(changedVariableValues), changedVariablesName);

print(changedVariableList);

track.stop();
```

Code for tracemem:

```
list1 <- list(a1 = 5, b1 = 6, c1 = 7);
list2 <- list(a2 = 1, b2 = 2, c2 = 3);
oldTraceList1 <- tracemem(list1);
oldTraceList2 <- tracemem(list2);

list1$a1 <- 6;
tracemem[0x000000000d918ec0 -> 0x000000000d918190]: 
newTraceList1 <- tracemem(list1);
newTraceList2 <- tracemem(list2);

identical(oldTraceList1, newTraceList1);
FALSE
identical(oldTraceList2, newTraceList2);
TRUE
```

Code for hash:

```
library(hashr);

list1 <- list(a1 = 5, b1 = 6, c1 = 7);
list2 <- list(a2 = 1, b2 = 2, c2 = 3);
oldHashList1 <- hash(list1);
oldHashList2 <- hash(list2);

list1$a1 <- 6;
newHashList1 <- hash(list1);
newHashList2 <- hash(list2);

identical(oldHashList1, newHashList1);
FALSE;
identical(oldHashList2, newHashList2);
TRUE
```

So, 1 question connected with "type" of objects - could I use any R type - vector, frame, S3-S4 classes, etc. (internal types) or external types like "R6 class" (R6 package, for example).
2 question connected with an execution - is it correct, that I'll always have identical(oldHashList1, newHashList1) as FALSE and identical(oldHashList2, newHashList2) as TRUE?

Comment: Can you please add an example code and the expected result because the question is difficult to understand? Thx!

Comment: Sure, I'll do this in 10-15 min, do not put question on hold, pls!

Comment: Hope, that's enough data...

Comment: Thank you, very helpful to understand your questions now. I hope somebody can help you, what you do is out of my experiences