# Strange addTaskCallback work in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r.net

This is my next question from cycle of "strange" questions.

I found same difference in code execution in R console and RStudio and couldn't understand reason of it. It's also connected with incorrect work of "track" package in RStudio and R.NET as I'd written before in [Incorrect work of track package in R.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798029/incorrect-work-of-track-package-in-r-net)

So, let's look at example from https://search.r-project.org/library/base/html/taskCallback.html

(I corrected it a little for correct data output for sum in RStudio)

```
times <- function(total = 3, str = "Task a") {
   ctr <- 0

   function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
    ctr <<- ctr + 1
    cat(str, ctr, "\n")
    if(ctr == total) {
      cat("handler removing itself\n")
    }
    return(ctr < total)
   }
 }

 # add the callback that will work for
 # 4 top-level tasks and then remove itself.
 n <- addTaskCallback(times(4))

 # now remove it, assuming it is still first in the list.
 removeTaskCallback(n)

## Not run: 
# There is no point in running this
# as
 addTaskCallback(times(4))

 print(sum(1:10))
 print(sum(1:10))
 print(sum(1:10))
 print(sum(1:10))
 print(sum(1:10))

## End(Not run)
```

An output in R console:

```
> 
>  # add the callback that will work for
>  # 4 top-level tasks and then remove itself.
>  n <- addTaskCallback(times(4))
Task a 1 
> 
>  # now remove it, assuming it is still first in the list.
>  removeTaskCallback(n)
[1] TRUE
> 
> ## Not run: 
> # There is no point in running this
> # as
>  addTaskCallback(times(4))
1 
1 
Task a 1 
> 
>  print(sum(1:10))
[1] 55
Task a 2 
>  print(sum(1:10))
[1] 55
Task a 3 
>  print(sum(1:10)) 
[1] 55
Task a 4 
handler removing itself
>  print(sum(1:10))
[1] 55
>  print(sum(1:10))
[1] 55
> 
> ## End(Not run)
>
```

Okay, let's run this in RStudio.
Output:

```
> source('~/callbackTst.R')
[1] 55
[1] 55
[1] 55
[1] 55
[1] 55
Task a 1 
>
```

Second run give us this:

```
> source('~/callbackTst.R')
[1] 55
[1] 55
[1] 55
[1] 55
[1] 55
Task a 2 
Task a 1 
>
```

Third:

```
> source('~/callbackTst.R')
[1] 55
[1] 55
[1] 55
[1] 55
[1] 55
Task a 3 
Task a 2 
Task a 1 
>
```

and so on.

There is a strange difference between RStudio and R console and I don't know why. Could anyone help me? Is is bug or it's normal and I have curved hands?

Thank you.

P.S. This post connected with correct working of "track" package, because "track.start" method consist this part of code:

```
assign(".trackingSummaryChanged", FALSE, envir = trackingEnv)
assign(".trackingPid", Sys.getpid(), envir = trackingEnv)
if (!is.element("track.auto.monitor", getTaskCallbackNames())) 
    addTaskCallback(track.auto.monitor, name = "track.auto.monitor")
return(invisible(NULL))
```

which, I think, doesn't work correct in RStudio and R.NET

P.P.S. I use R 3.2.2 x64, RStudio 0.99.489 and Windows 10 Pro x64. On RRO this problem also exists under R.NET and RStudio

Comment: I get the same behavior if I call `source(<file>)` in the R console; perhaps it's somehow related to directly evaluating the code in the console vs. within `source()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addTaskCallback()` will add a callback that's executed when R execution returns to the top level. When you're executing code line-by-line, each statement executed will return control to the top level, and callbacks will execute.

When executed within `source()`, control isn't returned until the call to `source()` returns, and so the callback is only run once.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, it works, thnxs! But, I can't use "Source" in RStudio for my code running each time? ((